# In Google script a function called by onEdit doesn't work as launched alone

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

from Google script if I launch my functions `Creaevento()` or `Cancellaevento()` alone they start and do their job correctly; however, if these functions are launched by `onEdit(e)` functions, they stop working when they arrive:

- here `var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId)`
- or here `var event = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId).createAllDayEvent(titolo, data)`

Any ideas?
Here's the code.
Thanks

```
function Cancellaevento() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var activeCell = spreadsheet.getActiveCell();
  
  /**Andare a inizio riga */
  var firstCell = activeCell.offset(0, 1-activeCell.getColumn());
  firstCell.activate();

  /**Recuperare valori dati */
  var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange("A2").getValue();
  firstCell.activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  var data = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getValue();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 2).activate();
  var titolo = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getValue();  
  
  //Accedere al calendario
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);

  firstCell.activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 4).activate();
  var eventID = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getValue();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});

  Browser.msgBox('Checkpoint');
  var event = eventCal.getEventById(eventID);
  
  // show event name in log
  Browser.msgBox('Cancellato "' + event.getTitle() + '" in data ' + event.getAllDayStartDate() + '\\n');
  
  //Eliminare evento
  event.deleteEvent();

  //Deflaggare evento
  firstCell.activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 5).activate();

  
};


function Creaevento() {

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var activeCell = spreadsheet.getActiveCell();
  
  /**Andare a inizio riga */
  var firstCell = activeCell.offset(0, 1-activeCell.getColumn());
  firstCell.activate();

  /**Recuperare valori dati */
  var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange("A2").getValue();
  firstCell.activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  var data = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getValue();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();  
  var mail = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getValue();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  var titolo = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getValue();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 5).activate();
  var consegna = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getValue();
  
  //Accedere al calendario
  Browser.msgBox('Checkpoint'); 

  //Creare evento
  var event = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId).createAllDayEvent(titolo, data/**, {description:consegna,guests:mail,sendInvites: true}*/);

  
  //Salvare eventID
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, -4).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue(event.getId());

  //Log
  Browser.msgBox('Evento "' + titolo + '" in data ' + data + ' creato con successo');
  
  //Flaggare evento
  firstCell.activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 5).activate();

  
};


function onEdit(e) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var checkbox = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getValue();
  //let cellCheck = (e.range.getColumn() == 6);
  //if (!(cellCheck)) {
  if (e.range.getColumn() == 6 && checkbox==true){
    Browser.msgBox('Lancio Crea evento');
    Creaevento();
  }else if(e.range.getColumn() == 6 && checkbox==false){
    Browser.msgBox('Confermi cancellazione evento?');
    Cancellaevento();
  }else{
    Browser.msgBox('None');
  }
}
```

Comment: Rename the function and create an installable trigger as suggested in the duplicate post.

Comment: Also in the execution page you can find the executions of all your functions. Since this is a trigger function and you can't see the executions upon executing it. You need to go to the execution page to see if your code has some errors. There you could see the exact error as the title of the duplicate question and therefore you could spot the solution easier.

Answer (score 0):

You should get out of the habit of using activate and getActiveCell.  In the case of an onEdit(e) you should transfer the e to the subfunctions and then the active cell will be e.range  then you can replace this:

```
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  var data = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getValue();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();  
  var mail = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getValue();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  var titolo = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getValue();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 5).activate();
  var consegna = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getValue();
```

With something like this:

```
var data = e.range.offset(0,1).getValue();
var mail = e.range.offset(0,2).getValue();
var titole = e.range.offset(0,3).getValue();
```

Actually a better way to do all of that is:

```
const sh=e.range.getSheet();
const values=sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart,1,5).getValues()[0];
const data=values[1];
const mail=values[2];
const titole=values[3]
```